# Set a list of images to an entity with VichUploaderBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I have an entity "Comment", and a "Comment" could have one or more images associated.
How do i achieve that.

Now i have this(for just one image):

```
/**
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize="1M",
 *     mimeTypes={"image/png", "image/jpeg"}
 * )
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="comment_mapping", fileNameProperty="imageName")
 *
 * @var File $image
 */
protected $image;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please review my comment and accept it if suitable otherwise comment what you don't understand then i will update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a [ManyToOne](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html) relationship between your Comment and Image entities.

Read more on associations with doctrine 2 [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html).

**Comment**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Image", inversedBy="comment")
 */
protected $images;

public function __construct()
{
     $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getImages()
{
    return $this->images;
} 

public function addImage(ImageInterface $image)
{
    if (!$this->images->contains($image)) {
        $this->images->add($image);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeImage(ImageInterface $image)
{
    $this->images->remove($image);

    return $this;
}

public function setImages(Collection $images)
{
   $this->images = $images;
}

// ...
```

**Image**

```
protected $comment;

public function getComment()
{
   return $this->comment;
}

public function setComment(CommentInterface $comment)
{
    $this->comment = $comment;

    return $this;
}

// ...
```

Then add a [collection form](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/collection.html) field to your CommentFormType with "type" of ImageFormType ( to be created ).

Comment: yes, but in that case i must to create a new entity Image. I want to know if is possible to do just using Comment entity and VichUploaderBundle

Comment: It is not possible without adding multiple image properties to your comment entity ... but that's just wrong.

Comment: ahh, ok, thanks, but that is crazy. Sometimes you know the number of  images, but sometimes not.